# How to align horizontally tikz picture and text in a tabular in LaTex?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have a table as shown below:

[image: tableVertAlign]

My code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,tikz}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=0cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tabular}{||p{1cm}|p{6cm}|p{8.07cm}|p{1cm}||}
\hline
1  & 
 \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-4:4,scale=0.8]
\draw (-0.1,2.8) -- (2.1,-1.5); 
\draw (-0.1,2.8) -- (-1.1,-1.5); 
\draw (-0.1,2.8) -- (3.1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
   Picture
 & A & B \\
\cline{3-4}
 & & C & D \\
 \cline{3-4}
 &  & E & F \\
 \cline{3-4}
 & & G & H \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I want to clear white space below tikz picture in column 2 and clear white space above column 3 so that the contents in these 2 columns aligned horizontally. I also want the contents in column 1 to be vertically and horizontally centered aligned. Anybody help me ? Thanks advance.
JEFF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally one would use multirow to overlap column 3 and the picture.  Instead, I used `\raisebox` to `\smash` the picture and computed how much space would be needed at the end.  The only fudge factor was the 1.6ex used to center the picture within the row.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,tikz}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=0cm]{geometry}
\newsavebox{\tempboxa}
\newsavebox{\tempboxb}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\savebox{\tempboxa}{\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-4:4,scale=0.8]
\draw (-0.1,2.8) -- (2.1,-1.5); 
\draw (-0.1,2.8) -- (-1.1,-1.5); 
\draw (-0.1,2.8) -- (3.1,0);
\end{tikzpicture} Picture}% compute height of picture

\savebox{\tempboxb}{\begin{tabular}{||p{1cm}|p{6cm}|p{8.07cm}|p{1cm}||}
 1 & & A & B \\
 \cline{3-4}
 & & C & D \\
 \cline{3-4}
 &  & E & F \\
 \cline{3-4}
 & & G & H \\
\cline{3-4}
\end{tabular}}% compute height of tabular

\begin{tabular}{||p{1cm}|p{6cm}|p{8.07cm}|p{1cm}||}
\hline
1  & \raisebox{\dimexpr 1.6ex-\ht\tempboxa}[0pt][0pt]{\usebox{\tempboxa}}
 & A & B \\
\cline{3-4}
 & & C & D \\
 \cline{3-4}
 &  & E & F \\
 \cline{3-4}
 & & G & H \\
\cline{3-4}
 & \rule{0pt}{\dimexpr \ht\tempboxa-\ht\tempboxb-\dp\tempboxb} & &\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: overlayed image in tabular]